# Wrong forwarding of rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I was experimenting with the newly added rvalue refernces ( in vs2012 express ).

I don't understand something tho. Given the code below ( most of it taken from the c++ standard where std::forward is explained ).

```
struct A
{
    A(int& i, const float& j):
        m_i(i),
        m_j(j){}

    int& m_i;
    const float& m_j;
};

template<class T, class A1, class A2>
T* factory(A1&& a1, A2&& a2)
{
    return new T(a1, a2);
}

void test()
{

    A* a1 = factory<A>(1, 1.2f);

    //How does this work ?        
    a1->m_i = 2;
}
```

I don't understand where is m_i binded to.

I will basically have a lvalue reference to an rvalue reference (& &&), that by the ref collapsing rules becomes (&) just a plain lvalue ref. But a reference to what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't understand where is m_i binded to.

`m_i` is bound to the argument of `A`'s constructor. What is the argument of `A`'s constructor here?

In this case, since `factory` does *not* forward its argument to `A` (i.e. it does not use `std::forward<>()`), then what is being passed to `A` is an *lvalue*. This is because `a1` is *named*, and **named objects are lvalues**.

The *type* of `a1` is not relevant to determine whether `a1` is an lvalue or an rvalue. So even though `a1` has type *rvalue-reference to* `int` (`int&&`), as is the case in your program, the parameter `a1` is itself a named object, and therefore it is an lvalue.

This means, since `m_i` has type lvalue-reference to `int`, that `m_i` **can** be bound (and indeed is bound) to `factory`'s (lvalue) parameter `a1`, which will be destroyed when `factory()` returns. In other words, you're left with a dangling reference.

Attempting to dereference it (as you do later on in your program) summons **Undefined Behavior**.

However, if your `factory()` function had *forwarded* its arguments to `A`'s constructor:

```
template<class T, class A1, class A2>
T* factory(A1&& a1, A2&& a2)
{
    return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));
}
```

This would have caused a compiler error, because the machinery of `std::forward<>()` would make sure that lvalues stay lvalues, and rvalues stay rvalues. Attempting to bind an lvalue-reference to an rvalue is illegal, and therefore the call to `A`'s constructor would have failed.

Comment: As Scott Meyers pointed out, any use of a universal reference (`T&&` with a type-deduced `T`) without either a `std::forward` or a `std::move` is at the very least dubious. Now I can clearly see why.

Answer (score 3):

> But a reference to what?

This is an undefined behavior. As you have guessed right, it is a reference to a temporary that was destructed in stack of the function `factory`. To catch such issues in compile time, you need to use `std::forward`

```
template<class T, class A1, class A2>
T* factory(A1&& a1, A2&& a2)
{
    return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));
}
```

Comment: `A1&& a1` need not be a rvalue_ref it can accept a lvalue_ref too as they type is deduced by the template. so whenever a type is deduced by template and you wan't to preserve the type of the reference across function calls, you have to use `std::forward`

Comment: ups....i accidentally deleted my coment. thanks. 
Old comment: do i always need to use std:: forward with lvalue references? )